# Pass variables from java to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript programming, and I have a question that I could not find an answer to anywhere.

I have some code in Java that does some stuff with two double arrays

```
double[] arrX = new double[sizeA];
double[] arrY = new double[sizeB];
```

Then, I need to pass these two variables to a html/JavaScript code that need to use them.

Is that possible?

Comment: You need to learn AJAX.

Comment: The above comment answered your question.

Comment: Not necessarily AJAX. They could be set as request attributes to be picked up in a JSP. But we don't know nearly enough about the OPs application to offer much help.

Comment: False. Its also possibly done as a Java Server Page (JSP)
Edit: GriffeyDog was faster :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It can be done in multiple ways and it depends on the architecture of your app and the frameworks that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would recommend following:

1. Install apached tomcat 
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/
2. Try Hello World example included in Apached Tomcat
   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/appdev/sample/

You would find values in variables shown in GUI.

Next Step assigning java variables to javascript variables, use following syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsVariable =<%javaVariable%>;
</script>
```

Hoping this helps.

Cheers !!

Comment: You better not give an example of scriplets to a newcomer.. :) Just give a hand in researching of Servlet API and JSP would be good.

Comment: @ConstantineNovykov - You are right, just though to tell hiim its possible.